# laravel/sanctum rest api token authorization failure with private token

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-sanctum

I created a sanctum personal token, but it will not authorize rest API call.

I am using bearer token in header 'Authorization' but will still redirect to login.

Creating token works fine:
http://localhost/api/sanctum/token

returns

> 2|hMASkhdQOzl7aOEL7G0At5A3yLZ0yWSLYNRy2kM7

am I supposed to use this output as a token?

Bearer `hMASkhdQOzl7aOEL7G0At5A3yLZ0yWSLYNRy2kM7`

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/deals', [DealController::class, 'create' ]);
```

Comment: this is for use in backend service, so i should not be authorized with a usernama/password

Comment: also token in database looks is not base encoded, not sure which to use

Comment: note that i am not very familiar with laravel and i did not make the system. i am trying to add REST API route

Answer (score 0):

You must access it by including the bearer token in the header like this:

[image]

Comment: ok ,but i dont have such type in n8n or boomerang

Comment: should be just

Authorization: Bearer <token>   header